# How to connect GitHub organization repo for App Engine Push-to-Deploy?

Tags: google-app-engine, github

I’m having a problem connecting a GitHub repository from an organization profile (not personal) to the Google Cloud Platform Developers Console / Releases section.

The problem is:

1. I don't have repositories in my GitHub account. Instead, I own an organization profile which has all the repositories we work in.
2. The dialog which appears on Connect button does not list organization repositories.
3. Entry of a repository URL is not available.

The pages that describe [configuring the GitHub repo](https://developers.google.com/cloud/devtools/repo/cloud-repositories#connecting_a_github_repository) mentions entering a URL, but the dialog has only the list (which is empty for me), and edit box for filtering.  Putting the repository URL into the filtering edit box (with checking “I consent”) does not give anything.

Is there any API-wise or another way to submit my organization repository for being used for Push-to-Deploy?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. From [their docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud/devtools/repo/cloud-repositories#connecting_a_github_repository) it looks like this was recently possible by entering the URL, but they must have changed it recently.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should access the Google Developer console with an user that has that repository in Github, so that it will be listed once you authorize the connection with OAuth.

I can't reproduce it as I don't have any organization repo in my github account.

Comment: To best of my knowledge, organizations [don't have direct user account](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-access-my-organization-account) associated with them. We do have access to repositories associated with the organization, but they are associated 'indirectly', and Console doesn't seem to support it.